# Which one is faster atomic_compare_and_swap or spin trylock?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, locking, lockless

Below is my use case

I have one global variable and multiple thread across all CPU are accessing this.

With atomic compare and exchange

```
auto old = global_var;
auto new_var = old
for (;;) {
            new++;
            bool got_it = atomic_compare_and_swap(global_var,
                                  old,
                                  new_var);
            if (got_it) {
                return new_var;
            }
            old = global_var;
            new_var = old;
    }
```

With spin trylock

```
for(;;)
    {
        auto temp = go_for_work();
        if (temp -> spin.trylock() == 0 )
        {
            continue;
        }

    }

... go_for_work
{
    auto old = global_var;
    auto new_var = old
    new_var++;
    global_var  =  new_var;
    return new_var
}
```

This is rough code I hope it is clear. Let me know if it is not clear.

global_var is not a int it is structure.

So, my main aim is to protect global_var, which one is faster atomic_compare_and_swap or spin.trylock(), also if some other technique ?

Comment: Side note: don't name your variable `new` that is a C++ keyword

Comment: Both are a busy loop - there is no difference (both are bad)

Comment: If the `global_var` type is integral, use an atomic increment.

Comment: This is rough as I can't post my code. global_var is not a int it is structure

Comment: @DieterLücking any better idea ?

Comment: @eswaat you might consider a condition variable

Comment: I can't sleep. can you give use case that fit my above condition.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: If `global_var` is not integral or a pointer type, the `atomic_compare_and_swap` is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a blocking test. non-blocking tests like a spin lock which at best is test and sleep in a loop take a lot of processor cycles at the detriment to all other processes. Try using a semaphore